# Nodejs, mongodb updating array on after insert many

Tags: node.js, mongodb, insert, buffer

Having some strange situation with a simple script on nodejs + mongodb.

I'm reading data from csv file, and after doing manipulation with data i want to save data into mongodb. Everything works fine with a single insert, but for better performance i want to use insert many, so here is my script:

```
parser.on('readable', function(){
 while(record = parser.read()){
   ...
   // Saving data in a buffer
   buffer.push({
     'name': cleared_name,
     'source': source,
     'notes': notes,
     'address': address[0]
   })

   // If buffer is more that 100 or we rich end of csv file - insert data into mongodb
   if(buffer.length >= 100 || readAllLines) {
      db.collection('peoples').insert(buffer, {w: 1, forceServerObjectId: false},  function(err, result) {
        lineCount -= result.insertedCount;

        // Close db connection if we insert all data
        if (lineCount === 0 && readAllLines) {
          db.close()
        }
        // Lets check what is in buffer right now
        console.log(buffer)
        // Clear buffer  
        buffer.length = 0;
        buffer = [] // or delete buffer;
      });
    }
 }
})
```

after inserting 200 rows, mongodb give me that error:

```
 AssertionError: {"name":"MongoError","message":"insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: databasename.peoples.$_id_ == null ...
```

and buffer array will contains that data:

```
[{ name: 'kelly',
source: 'Forbes.com',
notes: 'Scraped from box XX',
address: '104.236.115.138',
_id: 5565c77d8533c30967b5b278 },
{ name: 'kas',
source: 'Forbes.com',
notes: 'Scraped from box XX',
address: '184.168.221.28',
_id: 5565c77d8533c30967b5b279 },
{ name: 'alle',
source: 'Forbes.com',
notes: 'Scraped from box XX',
address: '82.118.66.19',
_id: 5565c77d8533c30967b5b27a }...
]
```

Even when i set forceServerObjectId to false on insert, mongodb set _id in buffer array. Is it possible to prevent that ?
And how can i clear buffer variable for sure ?

I guess problem that buffer still contains data that was already inserted, and mongo giving error because same ID is already exists in database (but i'm not sure that i 100% right)

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

The error can occur only if there exists a document in the database with some `_id`, say `ID1`, and you are trying to insert a new document which has `ID1` as its value for `_id` field.

This can be because of the following:

- You already have some documents in the collection, and there is a document in the collection and CSV file that share the same `_id`
- There are just at least two rows in the CSV file that share the same `_id`

If the value of `_id` field is not critical for you, you can just remove that attribute from your objects read from CSV right in your JavaScript code using `delete`.

Otherwise, you have a conflict, and need to decide what you want to do with duplicate `_id` documents. If you are ok with overwriting, you can achieve that by having `{upsert: 1}` option, which will update the document with new values in case if there is one existing with the same `_id`.

Comment: As you can see from a code above - i'm not push _id into buffer, and csv does not have _id field.  _Id appear in buffer after doing insertMany for a first time.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with closure for buffer:

```
 if(buffer.length >= 100 || readAllLines) {
    (function(buffer) {
       db.collection('peoples').insert(buffer, ... 
    })
    buffer = []
 }
```

But still looking for solution - how to not update buffer on insert